# What does it mean by the minimum of a fraction given 1?

Tags: notation

I saw an expression and was confused by that:

```
min{A/B |1}
```

Both A and B in my case are floating numbers.

The context is, say A is the mean proportion of the papers published in a certain subject in a certain country, and B is the maximum of A in a certain subject where the published paper counts exceeds the global average. I was told that it might be the case that 1 is the upper bound. I am not 100% sure though.

It is the notation from this link:
[Normalization](https://content.qs.com/qsiu/Faculty_Area_Normalization_-_Technical_Explanation.pdf)

Does that mean I have to find the minimum between (the fraction of A and B) and 1?

Also, This is my first post here.
Please feel free to let me know if I missed anything.
Thank you very much for all the help and reminders!

Comment: Some context might help.

Comment: Please inform us of where you encountered this notation, and in which context.

Comment: This expression doesn't have any meaning without further context.  If you are taking a class I'd advise asking your instructor.

Comment: Perhaps you are transcribing a hand-written expression? Is it conceivable that your vertical bar is supposed to be a comma?

Comment: It is not a notation I am aware of either. You might have better luck asking in the [data science forum](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/), since that is what this paper seems to be. This (and the use of $\equiv$ instead of $=$) may be a common notation in that specialization.

Comment: Thanks @Paul, I would give a try!